# Geting error while deploying CF over Bosh

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

Getting the following error while deploying CF over bosh

### Deploying

Director task 17
Deprecation: Ignoring cloud config. Manifest contains 'networks' section.

Started preparing deployment > Preparing deployment. Done (00:00:00)

```
Error 100: Unable to render instance groups for deployment. Errors are:
  - Unable to render jobs for instance group 'uaa_z1'. Errors are:
    - Unable to render templates for job 'uaa'. Errors are:
      - Error filling in template 'login.yml.erb' (line 202: Missing properties:\nlogin.saml.serviceProviderCertificate)
  - Unable to render jobs for instance group 'uaa_z2'. Errors are:
    - Unable to render templates for job 'uaa'. Errors are:
      - Error filling in template 'login.yml.erb' (line 202: Missing properties:\nlogin.saml.serviceProviderCertificate)

Task 17 error
```

Comment: Have you configured network section in Ops Manager Director?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a certificate. Maybe check that and the YAML format.